# Trying to get selector for img src & 'star rating' column in table w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I am trying to run some javascript/jQuery to essentially scrape the data from a table in the format below.
I have got most of this working however I am trying also grab the following data:-

a) The logo column (first column) - the image source e.g '/static/FIFA16/images/crest/50/light/21.png'
b) The 'star rating' column (last column), this doesn't have a number rating but an  tag with the format shown below.

I have then getting this data pushed into the result array - can anyone suggest how I grab the Logo (from the src of the image) and the Rating from counting the  tags and checking if the last  tag has the string 'half' within it?

```
<table class="table table-striped teams">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="logo">Logo</th>
        <th class="name">Name</th>
        <th class="league">League</th>
        <th class="starrating">Team Rating</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/team/21/fc-bayern/" title="FC Bayern"><img alt="FC Bayern" class="team small" src="/static/FIFA16/images/crest/50/light/21.png" title="FC Bayern"/></a></td>
        <td data-title="Name"><a href="/team/21/fc-bayern/" title="FC Bayern">FC Bayern</a></td>
        <td data-title="League"><a href="/teams/?league=19" title="Bundesliga">Bundesliga</a></td>
        <td data-title="Team Rating">
            <span class="star">
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star fa-lg"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star-half-o fa-lg"></i>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
..... more rows...
</tbody>
</table>
```

My jQuery code..

```
$(".table-striped tr").each( function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        icon = $tds.eq(0).text()
        club = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        league = $tds.eq(2).text(),
        rating = $tds.eq(3).text,

    result.push({
        icon : icon,
        club : club,
        league : league,
        rating : rating
    });
});
return result;
}
```

Comment: `$tds.eq(0).find('img').prop('src')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would recommend to change the selector to `$(".table-striped tbody tr")`, so that the header isn't loop (since there is no need to).

Then change

```
icon = $tds.eq(0).text()
...
rating = $tds.eq(3).text,
```

To

```
icon = $tds.eq(0).find('img').attr('src'),
...
rating = $tds.eq(3).find('i:first').attr('class');
```

I thereby assume that `rating` should result in the class name of the first `i`. In your example it results in `fa fa-star fa-lg`